# jQuery Mobile and Fullcalendar - select event

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, mobile, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use Fullcalendar with jQuery Mobile, and I want to call $.mobile.changePage when the user clicks on a time in the "Day" view - the even triggers, and it changes the url, but doesn't change away from the current page.

Has anyone integrated jQuery Mobile and Fullcalendar? Or know of any other calendars that may work better? I am writing a day-planner so need a day based view, where I can add events.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ - this is what I'm currently using.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, but using the fullcalendar select: method, and adapting some of the excellent Fullcalendar JS.